# Using underscore.js for null checking

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var name = "someName";
if(name !=null) {
   // do something
}
```

1. I am right now using http://underscorejs.org/#isNull, how would i do
   the same using `underscore.js`
2. Does it give any slight improvement in terms of performance for such
   functions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In underscore, you can use

```
if(!_.isNull(name)) {}
```

and in plain Javascript, you should use

```
if(name !== null) {}
```

You should avoid the loose inequality operator `!=` because it does type coercion and `undefined != null` will return `false`.

Using plain Javascript is slightly faster because it doesn't have to invoke a function, but it will be imperceptible and it should hardly be a consideration.

I don't have a strong preference either way as far as readability goes, but it seems a little excessive and verbose to call a library function for such a simple check.

Answer (score 1):

In underscore.js you must write this to achieve that functionality.

```
var name = "someName";
if(!(_.isNull(name ))) {
   // do something
}
```

In underscore.js function `isNull` is written like this

```
_.isNull = function(obj) {
    return obj === null;
  };
```

So the difference is using `==` in your code and `===` in underscore.js.For more details about that difference you can look in this question.

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

P.S. I will suggest to write your own condition instead of using any library in such simple place.

```
var name = "someName";
if(name !== null)) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: -1 for only mentioning the extreme simplicity of just writing `=== null`. Yes, I just downvoted Chuck Norris.

Comment: The greatest mistake of your life :D

Answer (score 0):

Well your original code is flawed because if `name` is an empty string, `false`, the number `0` or any other falsy value then it will be considered `null` as far as your test is concerned.

As a general rule, calling ANY function is an overhead that should be avoided if possible. In this case, calling a function just to test if a value is null, when you could very easily just write `if( name === null)`, is just stupid, IMO...

Comment: Just for people that are going to come to this question, no "", false and 0 will not match null, only undefined and null will match null when using == null.

On the other side, when checking for == false (or !something) THEN it'll also match null, undefined, 0, "", "0" and "false"

Comment: @XIU Thank you. `"0" == false` is always the one that gets me. What a crock…

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((!(_.isUndefined(data)) || _.isEmpty(data))) {
//Valid Data 
}else {//Not Valid}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Hi Shawn In case we need to perform some operation on json data /object so we can simple user he underscore library and perform 2 check first 

isUndefined (data) must be false and Is empty data is also valid so we jusy put condition for verify 


if (   !(_.isUndefined(data))   ||   _.isEmpty(data)  ) {
  //Valid Data json data 
  //TODO WORK
} else
{
  //Not Valid json result 
}